# Solr cloud page is not responding and creating a huge dump file

Tags: solr

Intermittently we are seeing the solr api url is not getting responded and at the same time the disk space is filled up with a core dump file of nearly 30gb

Unfortunately we are not able to open the dump file to see what’s going on?? Any one here faced similar kind of issue??

Also another data point here is, there is a process called something like qtp which is taking more memory like anything

Comment: Solr does not bundle any process named `qtp`. If you don't expect anything else to run on the server - are you sure you don't have a compromised server?

Comment: The servers have 160gb of RAM out of which there is 40 Gb dedicated to solr JVM and I confirm that this is a dedicated box for solr engine only.